# how to remove NA in summarize_all to summarize mutliple col at the same time?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, summarize

I have a dataframe like this and want to summarize the mean of every col ignoring NA using dplyr:

```
df= data.frame('var1'=sample(10,3),'var2'=sample(10,3), 'var3'=c(NA, NA,1), 'var4'=c(2,NA,6))
df %>% summarise_all(mean)
```

however, this will return NA in col 3 and 4.
How can I pass in na.rm=T?

Comment: Like this... `df %>% summarise_all(mean,na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: If you look at the documentation for `summarise_all` you can see that it has `...` allowing for additional arguments to be passed. So, for `mean` this means that you can pass its `na.rm` argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
> df %>% summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
  var1 var2 var3 var4
1    5    5    1    4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `mean_` from `hablar` that has `na.rm = T` as default:

```
library(hablar)
df %>% summarise_all(mean_)

      var1     var2 var3 var4
1 6.666667 4.666667    1    4
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use IDPmisc library 
example

```
M <- matrix(c(NA,1:7,NA),nrow=3)
M
NaRV.omit(M)
```